# Как определить, смог ли компилятор оптимизировать выделение памяти под корутину?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++20, coroutine

Как определить, смог ли компилятор оптимизировать выделение памяти под корутину? Те выделить память во фрейме вызывающей стороны? Я пробовал подсовывать пользовательский аллокатор, который писал сообщений в stdout при выделении. Такой эксперимент показал, что компилятор совершенно не оптимизирует аллокацию, даже при соблюдении всех требуемых условий. Я предполагаю, что такое поведение было вызвано наличием сайд-эффектов в виде вывода

Comment: Рассчитывайте, что компилятор ничего сам не оптимизирует.

Comment: @user7860670, я понимаю что нельзя расчитывать на оптимизацию, но хотелось бы пить код, который будет благоприятен для оптимизаций, для этого нужно понять как объяснить компилятору, что время жизни корутины вложено в вызывающую

Comment: Как бы, если заглянуть в ассемблер, ваш компилятор может это сделать, в принципе? Если да, то, вероятно, можно анализировать адрес локальной переменной, а если нет, то нужно искать другой компилятор.